# Помогите реализовать. Есть скрипт на генерацию кода+скидка

Tags: javascript

Задача такова. Есть скрипт который генерирует пароль и рандомную скидку %. Нужно что бы после нажатия на кнопку вылезала форма отправки сообщения на почту(почта к примеру 123@gmail.com) с данными  которые сгенерировал скрипт, пользователю нужно будет заполнить только одну форму его никнейм.

Код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>123</title>
    <script src="random.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="text-align: center;">

<button onclick="generate(this)">Generate!</button>
<div id="random" style="font-size: 25px; color: green; "></div>
<div id="random-percent" style="font-size: 25px; color: green; "></div>

</html>

function generate(el) {
  el.disabled = true;
  var pass = "";
  var strong = 5;
  var dic = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";

  for (var i = 0; i < strong; i++) {
    pass += dic.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * dic.length));
  }
  document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = pass;
  document.getElementById('random-percent').innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 3 + '%';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить форму, в которой будет, например только 1 input и кнопка submit:

```
  <form id="send-form" onSubmit="send();">
    <input id="name" placeholder="your nickname" />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
```

Далее сделать его сразу невидимым(в началае js файла):

```
document.getElementById("send-form").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

в функцию `generate` добавить отображение формы при генерации пароля:

```
  document.getElementById("send-form").style.visibility = "visible";
```

И собственно добавить функцию сабмита самой формы(для начала, залогировать введенное значение):

```
function send() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  console.log('name', name);
}
```

Остальные параметры у тебя уже есть, берешь все и отправляешь уже дальше